# Github losing correct author of commit through pull requests

Tags: git, github

My department has a fork of a github project.

I created a feature branch off of my departmental fork to fix a bug.  I then created a pull request into our departmental fork.  A co-worker reviewed the PR and accepted it into our departmental fork.  Upon reviewing the commit history on our fork, I am still the author of the commit.

Next step, my co-worker created a pull request of that commit into the master project that we forked from.  That pull request was accepted.  When I reviewed the commit history of the master project, the commit in question was shown to be authored by my co-worker and not myself.

I was expecting the author to be me.  Did we do something wrong in our multi-pull request scenario. or are my expectations incorrect?

Comment: It would help a lot to see the actual links. What you describe should not happen with regular merges. I'd guess the PR was accepted not as a merge but as a rebase ("squash"), so all you commits were put together and stored under the name of the Pull Requester (your colleague). But w/o actual links, it's hard to tell.

Comment: that actually makes a lot of sense.  I remember hearing something about PRs into the master projects were squashing commits down.